# WSO2 SIDDHI Query like "not exists"

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi

I have not found any way to express a query with something like "not exists".

For example, to simply test that all the devices are ok, or send an alert if one of them is missing for a given time, a query like :

```
from every myDeviceTable
join not exists myEvents[myEvents.DeviceID == myDeviceTable.ID]#window.time(5 sec)
select myDeviceTable.ID as deviceID, "Message...", ...
insert into myAlertTable
```

Some help please ?

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the not keyword as follows:
(Assuming myDeviceTable is an event table)

```
from myEvents[not(DeviceID == myDeviceTable.ID in myDeviceTable)] 
select DeviceID, "message..",
insert into myAlertTable;
```

If you want to select attributes that resides only inside the table, use another join query for that using the outputs of this query.